# synchronous loop for insertion of datavalue in SQLite

Tags: node.js, sqlite, synchronization, sequelize.js

I am using `sequelezer` to insert the values into local database. It kind of setup script that need to run on the first time on server.

Due to nodejs "asynchronous" function call, my sqlite db is getting lock and I get the following error
`Unhandled rejection SequelizeTimeoutError: SQLITE_BUSY: database is locked`

Here my code for that

```
    var country_json = {
      "AF": "Afghanistan",
      "AX": "\u00c5land Islands",
      "AL": "Albania",
      //........
      "ZW": "Zimbabwe"
    };

for (key in country_json) {

        console.log("ABUZAR");
        console.log(key.toString('utf8') + " " + country_json[key].toString('utf8'));

        db.country_name.findOrCreate({

                where: {
                    country_iso: key.toString('utf8')
                },
                defaults: {
                    country_name: country_json[key].toString('utf8')
                }
            })
            .spread(function(country, created) {
                console.log(country.get({
                plain: true
                }));
                console.log(created);
            });

    }
```

I tried few synchronous npm module , but each of them it seems working out. Just wanted to know how to handles these scenario in node js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mix async functions with cycles, logic, recursion, etc using [SynJS](https://github.com/amaksr/SynJS) - it will execute all the steps one-by-one in synchronous manner. Below is the script to illustrate:

```
global.SynJS = global.SynJS || require('synjs');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

var db = new Sequelize('tracker', 'tracker', 'tracker123', {
      host: 'localhost',
      dialect: 'mysql',
      pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        idle: 10000
      },
    });

function insertWrapper(db,context,key,value) { // <- wrapper function that returns initially incomplete result
    var res = {done: false};
    db.query("select CONCAT(?,'--->',?)", { replacements: [key,value], type: db.QueryTypes.SELECT })
    .spread(function(row) {
        console.log('done: row=',row);
        res.done = true;
        SynJS.resume(context); // once result is ready, it notifies context of caller function to continue
    });
    return res;
}

function myFunc(modules,db, country_json) { // <- function that is run via SynJS
    for (var key in country_json) {
        var res = modules.insertWrapper(db,_synjsContext,key,country_json[key]);
        SynJS.wait(res.done); // <-- wait for the callback to finish
    }
};

var modules = { // <-- convenience object to pass whatever myFunc may need, as it cannot access closures 
        insertWrapper:  insertWrapper,
};

var country_json = {
          "AF": "Afghanistan",
          "AX": "\u00c5land Islands",
          "AL": "Albania",
          //........
          "ZW": "Zimbabwe"
    };

// run myFunc via SynJS
SynJS.run(myFunc,null,modules,db,country_json,function () {
    db.close();
    console.log('done');
});
```

It would produce following output:

```
Executing (default): select CONCAT('AF','--->','Afghanistan')
done: row= { 'CONCAT(\'AF\',\'--->\',\'Afghanistan\')': 'AF--->Afghanistan' }
Executing (default): select CONCAT('AX','--->','Ã…land Islands')
done: row= { 'CONCAT(\'AX\',\'--->\',\'Ã…land Islands\')': 'AX--->Ã…land Islands' }
Executing (default): select CONCAT('AL','--->','Albania')
done: row= { 'CONCAT(\'AL\',\'--->\',\'Albania\')': 'AL--->Albania' }
Executing (default): select CONCAT('ZW','--->','Zimbabwe')
done: row= { 'CONCAT(\'ZW\',\'--->\',\'Zimbabwe\')': 'ZW--->Zimbabwe' }
done
```